# I want to enable textbox when checkbox is checked in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable textbox when checkbox is checked form content load from ajax page in modal popup but its not working and not showing any error in browser console.

[image]

```js
function cash(cash) {
  if ($(cash).is(':checked')) {
    $('#cashAmount').attr("disabled", false);
  } else {
    alert("checkbox is not checked");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 field-option">
  <strong>Cash</strong> <input type="checkbox" name="cash" id="cash" onclick="cash(this)">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 custom_field">
  <!-- custom_field -->
  <span><strong>Amount <i>*</i></strong></span>
  <input type="text" name="cashAmount" id="cashAmount" class="form-control" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: `.prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: i changed  .attr("disabled", false); to .prop("disabled", false); but nothing happen

Comment: `$('#cashAmount').prop("disabled", !cash.checked);`. No `if...else` needed I think.

Comment: It works on my side. using ff as browser

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this:

```
function cash(cash) {
 var getthevalue = $(cash).attr('id');
  if (getthevalue.is(':checked')) {               
    $('#cashAmount').attr("disabled", false);              
  }   
  else{
    alert("checkbox is not checked");
  }
}
```

This is because when you pass:

```
<strong>Cash</strong> <input type="checkbox" name="cash" id="cash" onclick="cash(this)">
```

You bass the html element and not the id, your **This** is referring to the entire strong tag.

So in your method:

```
var getthevalue = $(cash).attr('id');
```

Will get the ***id*** attribute of your input tag, which is passed through your this:

```
 onclick="cash(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript:

```
function cash(cash){
  if(cash.checked ===true) document.getElementById('cashAmount').removeAttribute('disabled');
  else document.getElementById('cashAmount').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when checkbox is checked form content load from ajax page in modal
>   popup

It seems you need to delegate the event

```js
// Using change event handler and delegating the event using on from body 
// to target element
$('body').on('change', '#cash', function() {
  // checking if it is checked
  if (this.checked === true) {
    $('#cashAmount').attr("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#cashAmount').attr("disabled", true);
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 field-option">
  <strong>Cash</strong> <input type="checkbox" name="cash" id="cash">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 custom_field">
  <!-- custom_field -->
  <span><strong>Amount <i>*</i></strong></span>
  <input type="text" name="cashAmount" id="cashAmount" class="form-control" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#cash").on('change', function(){
     $('#cashAmount').attr("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 field-option">
  <strong>Cash</strong> <input type="checkbox" name="cash" id="cash">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 custom_field">
  <!-- custom_field -->
  <span><strong>Amount <i>*</i></strong></span>
  <input type="text" name="cashAmount" id="cashAmount" class="form-control" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bimalkumarh/d1qxv247/

```
$("#cash").on('change',function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#cashAmount').attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      alert("checkbox is not checked");
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following code using Javascript

```js
function cash(x) {

  if (document.getElementById('cash').checked) {

    document.getElementById("cashAmt").disabled = false;

  } else {

    document.getElementById("cashAmt").disabled = true;


  }

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 field-option">
  <strong>Cash</strong> <input type="checkbox" id="cash" onclick="cash(this)">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 custom_field">
  <!-- custom_field -->
  <span><strong>Amount <i>*</i></strong></span>
  <input type="text" id="cashAmt" class="form-control" disabled>
</div>
```

Following code uses jquery

```js
function cash(cash) {
  if ($(cash).is(':checked')) {               
    $('#cashAmt').attr("disabled", false);              
  }   
  else{
    $('#cashAmt').attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 field-option">
    <strong>Cash</strong> <input type="checkbox" id="cash" onclick="cash(this)">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 custom_field"> <!-- custom_field -->
    <span><strong>Amount <i>*</i></strong></span>
    <input type="text" id="cashAmt" class="form-control" disabled>
  </div><!-- End custom_field-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) config to disable [`textbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) on click of [`checkbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

```js
function handleChange(el) {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    name.disabled = !el.checked;
    name.focus()
}
```

```html
<label><input type='checkbox' onclick='handleChange(this);'>Checkbox</label>
<br>
<label>Name : <input disabled=true type='text' id='name'></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Smallest, simplest and easiest thing to do, using the `true/false` state of checkbox thereby avoiding `if-else`:

```js
$('body').on('change', '#cash', function() {
  $('#cashAmount').prop("disabled", !this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 field-option">
  <strong>Cash</strong> <input type="checkbox" name="cash" id="cash">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 custom_field">
  <!-- custom_field -->
  <span><strong>Amount <i>*</i></strong></span>
  <input type="text" name="cashAmount" id="cashAmount" class="form-control" disabled>
</div>
```